# Unable to install jdk-8u101-windows-x64 in system

Tags: java

After uninstalled the java in my computer, i have downloaded latest version jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe and tried to install it. but unfortunately at end of installation i got the error code as,

[Error message which i got during installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IycSh.png)

I have followed the steps as described in the java help site. but nothing gives me the solution. Because of this i cant even launch the Eclipse to code.

Comment: Are you 100% sure of your CPU architecture? What steps did you take after the error occurred?

Comment: @stefanobaghino further to this, i came to know that i have problem in my laptop missing .dll kind of files. When i launch windows -> All programs -> java development kit ->  'Java mission control' , APP CRASH occurred with  fault module name - ntdll.dll. trying to figuring out the solution to this.

Comment: Finally i gave up finding the root cause to resolve this issue and installed new OS. Then installed the required jdk successfully. Now i can work as i expected.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle **site**,

This is a **known** issue.

> Error 1603: Java Update did not complete.
>
> WORKAROUND This is a known issue, and we are still investigating the
>   root cause. Meanwhile you can try the following to install Java.

**Workarounds:**

**Option 1:** Restart your system and uninstall old versions

**Option 2:** Disable Java content through the Java Control Panel

You can follow more detailed steps from this official [link](https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml).

Comment: Surprisingly I couldnt find 'Java control panel' in my laptop. So unable to perform the workarounds as suggessted here

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link, it is an issue with Java it is under investigation
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml